# open a jquerymobile popup programmatically in an if-statement

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, popup

I want to open a jquerymobile popup in an if-statement. If I run that page in my browser I get following error in my console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PopUp</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css"/>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    </head>
     <body>

        <body>
            <div data-role="page" data-theme="d">
                <div data-role="content">
                    On this page a popup should be opened programmatically
                    <?php 
                        $simple = "simple";
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var simple = '<?php echo $simple; ?>';
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            if(simple == "simple"){
                            $( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" );
                            }
                        });
                    </script>

                    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDiv">
                        <p>PopUp erfolgreich</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

What do I have to change in my code, to get the right result as intended?

Comment: You haven't included whatever it is that defines "popup".  Also, you're including jQuery *twice*. Don't use "jquery-latest."

Comment: If I delete the jquery-latest it works. Thanks Pointy!